# How to debug or narrow down logic errors?

Tags: javascript, processing

I am trying to debug this game I am making. Something is wrong with the for loops and I do not know what it is; essentially I am trying to get my rectangles to spawn on the canvas after the user clicks ready. What are some ways to debug logic errors? Doing this over khanacademy.

When I println the drawRects function. Console says infinite loop and points to my for loops.
[image: snippet1]

When I click ready, the console increases by 1 each time so I know the levelUp function is working.

[image: snippet2]

I cant post another link because not enough rep, but when I println randomRects, nothing appears on the console.

Therefore, I believe it is safe to assume something is wrong with my for loops, because the levelUp function works but the random rectangles are not appearing. What are other debugging techniques I can use to narrow down the problem?

Comment: In the first link, you `.push(randomRects)`, the second you `.push(randRect)`. Which should it be? And where is what you're pushing defined? Should you be trying `.push(randRect())` (calling a function)?

Comment: I don't know which it should be, I was essentially guessing. `var randomRects = [];` is a global variable defined on the second line. I tried `randomRects.push(randRect());` and it does not do anything. randRect is a defined function that contains a random x, y, width, height and colors.

Comment: Classic debugging methods are to place `console.log()` in your code to check the value of certain variables at critical points, like just before entering a `for` loop. In your case, I noticed one of your loops has a condition that check the `length` property of an object. If that property has value `undefined` or something weird, it could always return false and create an infinite loop. First thing I'd do in your case is double check that my variables exist (they are `!== undefined` ) and that the properties you need also exist and have a value you expect (length should be a number)

Answer (score 1):

You debug a problem by finding out exactly what the code is doing.

There are a few ways to do that:

**Use your head.** This is your first line of defense. Run through the code in your head, or better yet with a piece of paper and a pencil. Use some example values for your input, and walk through line by line and see what the code would do. Talk out loud, write stuff down, and do this over and over again. This is a huge part of being a programmer.

**Use a console.** Processing has a `println()` function that should go to your JavaScript console in your browser. This is your new best friend. Print out the values of any variables you want to know about, like this:

```
println("x: " + x);
```

Or a simple `println("here")` inside an `if` statement can tell you whetehr that `if` statement is executing. Combine this with approach one to really check all of your assumptions.

**Use a debugger.** If all else fails, step through your code with a debugger. This is basically using a computer to do the first two approaches.

In reality, you'll use a combination of all of the above to debug a problem. But the basic idea is this: you need to understand what your code is doing. You do that by first running through the code in your head or on a piece of paper, and you test any assumptions or anything you aren't sure by printing stuff out.